# print data in hashmap in a tabular format in log file

Tags: java, string, logging, collections

Hi here i want to print the data of hashmap in the tabular format.Below is my code to insert the data in hashmap.

```
 String foldername = item.getParent().substring(item.getParent().lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                        statusname = foldername + "\t" + _DeployResult.ServerIP + "\t" + _DeployResult.ServerType;
                        if (!Prdeploy.statusmap.containsKey(statusname)) {
                            Prdeploy.statusmap.put(statusname, 0);
                        }
```

and below is code which is written to print the data in the log file:

```
 logger.info("****************Summary Report****************");
                   logger.info("Folder\tServer\tType\tFailed");

        for (String name: statusmap.keySet()){

            String key =name.toString();
            String value = statusmap.get(name).toString();  

            System.out.println(key + "  " + value);  
            logger.info(key + "\t" + value);
} 
        logger.info("**********************************************");
```

here i am getting the output of above as below:

```
****************Summary Report****************
Folder  Server  Type    Failed
180_Perl_Scripts            10.5.50.195 SS  0
050_Images              10.5.50.195 SS  0
020_XSL             10.5.50.195 SS  0
srf             10.5.50.195 SS  0
030_XSLT            10.5.50.195 SS  0
bscript 10.5.50.195 SS  0
bscript 10.5.50.195 WS  1
010_StyleSheets             10.5.50.195 SS  0
040_WebTemplates            10.5.50.195 SS  0
050_Images              10.5.50.195 WS  0
060_js_Files            10.5.50.195 SS  0
010_StyleSheets             10.5.50.195 WS  0
**********************************************
```

but i want my output as below:

```
    ****************Summary Report****************
Folder                  Server          Type    Failed
180_Perl_Scripts            10.5.50.195 SS  0
050_Images              10.5.50.195 SS  0
020_XSL                     10.5.50.195 SS  0
srf                     10.5.50.195 SS  0
030_XSLT                    10.5.50.195 SS  0
bscript                 10.5.50.195 SS  0
bscript                 10.5.50.195 WS  1
010_StyleSheets             10.5.50.195 SS  0
040_WebTemplates            10.5.50.195 SS  0
050_Images              10.5.50.195 WS  0
060_js_Files            10.5.50.195 SS  0
010_StyleSheets             10.5.50.195 WS  0
**********************************************
```

Here i am not able to put the exact pattern.But just i want it into tabular format.Well structired.
Is there way to do this? Please help me here!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
String str = String.format("%-10s%-10s%-10s%s", statusMap.get("Folder"), statusMap.get("Server"), statusMap.get("Type"), statusMap.get("Failed"));
logger.info(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can format your strings using String.format methods.

```
`logger.info(String.format("%-20s %-20s%-10s%-10s" , "Folder", "Server", "Type", "Failed" ));`
```

Where %s is a placeholder for you string.
The '-' makes the result left-justified.
20 and 10 is the width of the strings

Answer (score 0):

If you only need this for display purposes, that is you don't really need it to be tab characters then it would be easy to create a padRight() or padLeft() methods which would pad the string with spaces

Something like:

```
String padRight(String inputStr, int length)
{
   while(inputStr.length() <= length)
       inputStr = inputStr + " ";
   return inputStr;
}
```

This could easily be modified to accept any character you wish to pad with also.

Answer (score 0):

With tab it won't be easy. What you have to understand with tab is that it comes in groups of spaces. I think the default value of a tab is 4 spaces. This works like this.

> Start__*middle*_end

The group of underscores is one tab. Every underscore is one space. 
You have `Start` which is of length 5. So it overlapses by 1. So when you press tab it will go in the position 8 (like two tabs of 4) which is 3 spaces. Same with middle.

What you need to use is the [formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)